# how to search multi query in mongodb when the key is passed in the req parameter?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

The search key is dynamically passed in via the id parameter when an get request calls this api.

We're finding the objects that has the Later_Today_P property set to true.

Sample mongo schema:

```
   {  "user_logged_email" : "liblibraryzone@gmail.com",
        "Counter_P" : false,
        "Negotiation_Willing_P" : false,
        "Grey_P" : false,
        "Left_VM_P" : false,
        "Later_Today_P" : false,
        "No_Updated_P" : false,
    }
```

This was works great:

```
exports.Later_Today_P_prioritySearch = function(req, res, next, id) {
    var id_2  = id;
    var dynamicId={};
    dynamicId[id_2]=true;

    Property.find(dynamicId).exec(function(err, properties) {
```

but now I need to grap the objects where the Later_Today_P is set to true and also where the user_logged_email = "libraryemail@gmail.com"

following isn't working.

```
Property.find({dynamicId, user_logged_email : "libraryemail@gmail.com" }).exec(function(err, properties) {
```

Try 1:

For some reason the data is showing up but its screwed up.

```
var id_2  = id;
var dynamicId={};
dynamicId[id_2]=true;

var id_3  = "user_logged_email";
var dynamicEmail={};
dynamicEmail[id_3]="libertytrustgroupllc@gmail.com";
```

// this works

```
Property.find(dynamicEmail).exec(function(err, properties) {
```

// this works
    Property.find(dynamicId).exec(function(err, properties) {

// but this doesnt work, for some reason.

```
Property.find(dynamicEmail, dynamicId).exec(function(err, properties) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query filter is incorrect.

Something like

```
var id_2=id;
var filter={};
filter[id_2]=true;
filter["user_logged_email"]="libraryemail@gmail.com";
```

This will result in `{ "Later_Today_P" : true, "user_logged_email" : "libraryemail@gmail.com" }`

Continue with same query:

```
Property.find(filter).exec(function(err, properties) {
```

Comment: Can you show me your updated code pls ? You've to merge the query filter into one document. It can't be two documents as shown in your latest try.`find(dynamicEmail, dynamicId)`